# Magnification of Objective Lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Where should we place an object to get 10x magnification with a 10x objective lens? we know that objective lens can be modeled with a simple positive lens so magnification should be dependent on the position of the object.

Comment: Linear magnification is equal to image distance divided by object distance.

Comment: Magnification does not depend from "lens size", but from the focal distance. If you combine two lenses into collimated system, your magnification is $F/f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear magnification of the objectif is in relation with the "tube length" of the microscope, which fix the point where the image given by the objective must be.

Usually, $\Delta =F{{'}_{1}}{{F}_{2}}=160\ \text{mm}$ and so the magnification is $\frac{\Delta }{f'}$ (since the focal length of the objective is small compared to the tube length).

Sorry for my poor english !

Answer (score 0):

Edit after first mistake...

I am guessing that a x10 lens means that when the objective lens of x10 is part of a system that gives x10 magnification.

The magnification given by a single lens changes depending on the object distance, $u$.

Now you can used the lens equation

$$ {1 \over f} = {1 \over u} + {1 \over v} $$

to find a condition where

$$ v= 10u$$

because if the image distance is ten times the object distance then the image will be ten times bigger than the image.

Note also that normally the way we use lenses to magnify as a magnifying glass is to make a virtual image so that the values of $u$ and $v$ will be opposite signs - one will be positive and one will be negative so really we want to use the equation

$$ v= -10u$$

earlier mistake below...

I thought that x10 was because the lens had a 'power' of 10. If it had then power is 1/focal-length, where focal length is in metres. So the focal length would have been .1m or 10 cm.

Comment: No, I didn't mean power by 10x. I mean the number that Objective lenses are usually characterized by, 10 times linear magnification.

Comment: @mjm - I suggest that you put some more detail into your question to describe the number of lenses in your system and exactly which distances you need....

Comment: Magnification is not power: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification

Comment: @safesphere - thanks for the comment - answer edited, may make a bit more sense now...